# Web sockets doesn't reconnect after internet connection is lost in Firebase - Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, websocket, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app using Ionic Framework and Firebase. I've been reading a lot about the subject (Websockets not reconnecting after Internet connection comes back) and I found that I'm not alone with this issue.

I can create new nodes without internet connection (I put the phone in airplane mode to simulate the lost of the connection), but when the Internet connection comes back, Firebase doesn't synchronize the information.

I suspect that Socket reconnection is the problem because even if I stop using airplane mode the connection never comes back, and the new nodes never syncs.

I've tried `Firebase.goOnline()` and `Firebase.goOffline()` with no results or changes in the behavior of the connection status.

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem ? thanks

Comment: Not really, I opted to choose another NoSQL technology